# Supremum of random variables evaluated at the inverse of their densitiy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails, large-deviation-theory

Assume $X_1$, ..., $X_n$ are random variables (might be independent or not) with the same marginal density $f$ having finite moments to any desired order. I want to reach a tight tail distribution of the quantity:
$$
\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\frac{1}{f(X_i)}
$$

- Is the order of magnitude of $E\left[\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\frac{1}{f(X_i)}\right]$ known in the bibliography? I didn't find any meaningful result.
- Are there any results regarding the tail distribution of $\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\frac{1}{f(X_i)}?$

What I can prove for the moment is that for large a, $P\left(\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\frac{1}{f(X_i)} > n^{a}\right)$ converges to 0 at a rate $n^{-\beta}$ for $\beta > 0$.

I seek a faster tail decay.

Comment: It doesn't matter if this happens for a small probability event. I want to have an idea about the probability of the event when this does not happen. Btw, the random variables cannot be equal to 0 with probability 1 since they are generated by a probability densitiy.